# How to convert this Python code into a shell script?

Tags: python, shell

```
import datetime   

def get_a_week(start) 
    date = datetime.datetime(start)
    dates = []
    for i in range(7):
        date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        print(date)
        dates.append(date)
    return dates

7_days = get_a_week('2022-09-01')
```

I need to periodically download files from remote machine, and part of the file name is a date, such as:

```
file_20220901
```

Each time I want to download 7 files for seven sequential days, so I need to use a logic like above to download files. How to covert this python code above into a shell script? It will download files using this command:

```
rsync x.x.x.x::user2/workspace/waic/tag/data/tag.20220901 data
```

Comment: Immediately noticed: `7_days` will not work as a variable name.

Comment: Think first on how you want to represent the list of dates in your shell script. In Python, you are using an array. In POSIX shell, you don't have arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a for loop.

```bash
start="2022-09-02"
for i in {0..6}
do
  : $((d=$(date -d "$start + $i day" +"%Y%m%d")))
  echo "RANDOM_TEXT_$d"
  # you can replace the echo above by the command that you want.
done
```

Or in a POSIX shell:

```bash
start="2022-09-02"
: "$((i=1))"
while [ "$((i != 7))" -ne 0 ]
do
    : $((d=$(date -d "$start + $i day" +"%Y%m%d")))
    echo "RANDOM_TEXT_$d"
    : "$((i = i + 1))"
done
```

Job done :)

Note: on OS X the date command may be different.

Comment: AFIK, `{0..6}` does not work in a POSIX shell. BTW, using backquotes for command substitution is considered obsolete nowadays.

Comment: Also, note that we frown on answering "please translate this code to language X" questions in general -- see the Answer Well-Asked Questions section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the sections of the Help Center linked therein. Or, even more on-point: [Is "How do I convert code from ${this language} to ${this language} too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad)

Comment: ...it would be different if the OP asked a question about a specific problem they encountered trying to write the code themselves. "How do I increase a date by a day in bash?", for example, is a narrow question that's narrow and specific enough to be on-topic; but for that reason, it's _also_ already asked-and-answered, so reasking it would be a duplicate.